# Python: YAML data parsing from a file

Tags: python, yaml

I have YAML data as below

```
- gms:
  - localhost1:
      address: 192.168.56.101
      username: root
      password: xxxxxx
      command: "uptime"
      hostname: mydev_machine
```

and I am trying to extract values of `address`,`password`,`command`,`hostname` with below logic in python

```
import yaml

with open("host_data.yaml",'r') as stream :
  data_loaded = yaml.load(stream)

for element in data_loaded:
  address=element['gms']['localhost1']['address']
  username=element['gms']['localhost1']['username']
  password=element['gms']['localhost1']['password']
  hostname=element['gms']['localhost1']['hostname']
```

if I look at `print(data_loaded)` output

```
[{'gms': [{'localhost1': {'address': '192.168.56.101', 'username': 'root', 'password': 'xxxxxx', 'command': 'uptime', 'hostname': 'mydev_machine'}}]}]
```

but I am getting error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Python_Programs/log_finder.py", line 12, in <module>
    address=element['gms']['localhost1']['address']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: What is the output of `print(data_loaded)` after `data_loaded = yaml.load(stream)`? You should do some basic debugging first. Also, it's not clear where the `'gms'` key comes from.

Comment: @roganjosh, updated. And changed `gms` to `dev`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element.get('gms')` or `element['gms']` yields a list. You need to iterate the list.

```
for element in data_loaded:
    for item in element.get('gms'):
        print(item.get('localhost1').get('address'))
```

You can also access the elements of the `list` like this:

```
element['gms'][0]['localhost1']['address']
```

Comment: Working. So [0] indicates dictionary at [0] index ?

Comment: Yes. The first element of the `[{'localhost1': {'address': '192.168.56.101', 'username': 'root', 'password': 'ramaram', 'command': 'uptime', 'hostname': 'mydev_machine'}}]` list. I would suggest you to iterate the list instead of using index number.